# Options for performing load testing with identity tokens

Tags: openid, performance-testing, load-testing, identityserver3

I have an API that is expecting OpenID Connect user tokens generated by an IdentityServer3 instance that I also manage. I need to perform load testing on the API, and am not sure of the best way to go about this.

The non-protected parts of my API are fairly easy to test. However, several API methods require the user to be authenticated with a bearer token.

Are there standard approaches to load testing when using OpenID Connect tokens, or IdentityServer3 in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Given `bearer token` it seems your application uses [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) so you need a load testing tool which:

1. Can send an [Authorization HTTP Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) containing the token
2. Preferably have mechanism to automatically or semi-automatically get the token

Check out for example:

- [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) -> [OAuth2 Authorization](https://www.soapui.org/oauth2/reference/oauth-2.html)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) -> [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)